# Get map key value and set the Expandable listview parent textview

Tags: java, android

I have one issue, Get the map key values and set the value in the expandable listview parent textview, The parent group size is dynamic

For example, I have parent group size is 2.

Parent textView 1 - History Status : Process

Parent textView 2 - History Status : Completed

Can you tell me the solution for this issue.

Sample code

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;      
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();              
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.history_status_view, parent, false); 
            holder.history_status = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.history_status);


        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
            for (Entry<String, List<History>> entry: map.entrySet()) {

            holder.history_status.setText(entry.getKey().toString());

        }



        return convertView; 
    }
```